# Error:null value in entry: mainDexListProguardOutputFile=null

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am getting this error in Android studio while gradle build.

```
Error:null value in entry: mainDexListProguardOutputFile=null
```

build.gradle:

> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>
> compileSdkVersion 24
> buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
> defaultConfig {
>     applicationId "xxx"
>     minSdkVersion 15
>     targetSdkVersion 24
>     versionCode 14
>     versionName '2.4'
> }
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>
>         debuggable false
>         minifyEnabled false
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>
>     }
>     debug {
>         debuggable true
>         minifyEnabled true
>     }
> }
> productFlavors {
> } 
> }
>
> repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     ---
> }
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
> ```

clean build didn't work, how can I fix this?

Comment: share your gradle file

Comment: bug in the gradle

Comment: @kevanaghera build.gradle added

Comment: what is error when u try to build that? and where is your all compile library? u import project?

Comment: error:null value in entry: mainDexListProguardOutputFile=null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too late to answer of my own question:

> delete **.gradle** folder from root directory then rebuild.